# When array is full, lock it, do some task with it, all while still accepting new elements into the array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node webserver and a redis database. I will be receiving thousands of small requests every second. These requests will contain data which will need to be inserted into the redis database. For performance reasons I want to use a feature called redis streams where I will have an constant open stream to the redis databse I will use batch inserts to increase write performance. For me to do batch inserts I will first need to receive the requests, store them on the webserver, and when I reach the threashold I will need to take all this data, create a batch redis command to insert everything and send it to the database. I need to be able to store these requests temporally until they can be inserted into the database.

This is some code to an incomplete idea I have because I am not sure the best way to implement this. I start of with an array which will store the requests. When this array becomes full (has 1000 elements) I will lock it. I will then take this array and create redis command with the data inside and send it to the database. The problem here though is while I locked this array, no new requests will be recorded even though during this time thousands of new requests could come in. I need to be able to handle this unknown number of these requests dynamically while still being able to send data over to the database.

```
//Just some dependencies to create a webserver and redis client, not important for this question
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

//Once this array has 1000 elements in it it will need to be taken and saved to the database. 

var pending_batch_operation_items=[];

app.get('/someData', function (req, res) {

/*
1)Check if the array is not full or locked, the data from this request
  pending_batch_operation_items.add(req.param)

2)If it is full lock the array and send the data over to redis:

   pending_batch_operation_items.lock=true;

  for (i = 0; i < pending_batch_operation_items=.length; i++) { 
    client.set('key', pending_batch_operation_items[i]);
}
pending_batch_operation_items.false=true;

but at this time I must also be able to to receive requests coming in this very second as well. In the next 3 seconds I could receive thousands of requests and I am not sure how to do this.

*/        

})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you lock it? The application is single threaded so you don't need any locking mechanisms in place.

Just check if the queue/array is full then create the batch, sent it to the DB then clear it.

Because is single threaded, the new connections will wait until the sending to DB finishes.

Comment: The inserts could take some time so the call to redis is async as I do not want to block the server during this time. So while the call is being made the nodejs server will be doing nothing so during this time I would like it to still receive requests which is what I am having trouble to implement.

Comment: man, you won't block anything if that call to redis is async; async means that it returns immediately so after that `for` will finish you clear the queue and only after that `function (req, res)` will return then new requests will be processed. Keep in mind that is **single threaded**